# Can an order from physical store be cancelled if delivery date keeps being pushed back several months after first delivery date?

Tags: united-states, consumer-protection, connecticut

I ordered a GE range at a physical store in my hometown on March 1st 2021 with scheduled delivery date in April.

Since then the delivery has been pushed back 3 times with a vague promise in June for September 2021.

As I'm prepared to call up the store again to get an update, can I ask to be refunded? So far the sales rep has said there was nothing he could do than wait on the supplier's delivery, implying I wasn't eligible to cancel.

My Sales Order states: "special orders are non-cancelable and non-refundable".
However what is a special order given the range was in their catalogue ?

Is a consumer eligible to cancel after such a long delay, from a physical store?

Notes:

1. because of the pandemic some parts from China have been out of stock, especially on induction ranges.
2. In order to take advantage of a GE promotion for additional goods, I've paid the range in full. Now the promotion may even be expired as it was contingent on the delivery date. Can I enforce the promotion due to unacceptable delivery timeline?

Fun fact:
3. This is taking so long the first sales rep happened to go on retirement before the delivery!

Thank you!
G